# Why is an inline-block not "visible"?

Tags: jquery

Inline-block seems to make elements not match the ":visible" selector?

```
$('body').append($('<p>').css('display', 'inline-block'))
var p = $('p');
p.is(':visible');
==> false

p.css('display', 'block');
p.is(':visible');
==> true
```

Comment: Your code returns `false` for me in both cases, as it should as your element is detached from the DOM.

Comment: @Mr.Alien OP is creating a new `p` element.

Comment: sorry, yeah I skipped the adding to dom step in my sample code-- i updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) :

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

An empty inline-block will have a height and width of 0 (the width is based on the contained elements)

[image]

An empty block element will have a width of the parent element

http://i.snag.gy/cLLei.jpg

More info can be found at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) on how width is determined for inline and block level elements.

**Edit:** As Fabrício Matté points out, this assumes the elements are both empty and appended to the DOM. Detached, even the block element has no parent to calculate layout and will return false.

Comment: None of them consume space in the document while they're detached from the document.

Comment: You're right. I appended the nodes to the document to verify.

Comment: Should probably note that this assumes the element is appended to the DOM, which is not clear from the question.